# laravel nova hide edit button on index page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-nova, laravel-authorization

How to disable edit/delete button on nova index page and still allow in detail page, if I will create a policy, that will disable the operation everywhere, I want to allow edit and delete in detail page, but just want to remove those button from index,

is doing something like

```
 public function update(User $user, Customer $customer)
    {
        if ( request()->route()->getName('route-name') ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

is correct way or there is any better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to disable any row button on index page, create a policy for the resource and return false on the respective function in my case `update()`,

all others return true and add the policy on AuthServiceProvider.php add

```
protected $policies = [
    Post::class => PostPolicy::class,
];
```

and in Resource class

```
public static function authorizable()
{
    return true;
}
```

that will disable that button.

Comment: It will hide the button, but it'll also disable any custom operations, in this case under the `edit` authorization policy. That's not what the user asked. The user asked to keep the policy but hide the button only.

Comment: @Max  please check the question, it is mentioned to disable in index page and allow in details page. Hiding is not same as disabling.

Comment: I checked the question. You should check the question. He wants to remove the buttons from index without disabling the operations. Your answer will not work, because it will disable ‘edit’ everywhere, even in detail view, and allow all other operations.

Comment: @Max I am the person who has asked the question, so I am very clear about the requirement. I hope your answer too helpful for others and yourself. My answer was exactly what I wanted before posting this question.

Comment: @Max 1st let me clear you, for this CSS is never ever ever a solution, in policy class return false in index method and true in show method, will disable buttons in index page and allow it on detail page. By the way I have more than 6000 reputation, that means I have something, I guess.

Comment: There’s no index method, or show method. Even your answer doesn’t talk about index or show method.

Comment: @max I don’t think people who works in Laravel will need Policy class here, they will go through documentation to learn details of Policies instead and if they know, this answer should be enough to understand how it works with Nova resource.

Answer (score 7):

I know this thread is a little old but you can also override the `authorizedToUpdate` method from within your nova resource like so:

```
public function authorizedToUpdate(Request $request): bool
{
    return "nova-api/{resource}" != $request->route()->uri();
}
```

This also works for `authorizedToView` and `authorizedToDelete`.

Comment: You can just add: `return false;`.

Comment: Thanks this works for me only in index page.

Answer (score 4):

I had a resource of Leads and I needed to hide the edit button on it. I did the following, in my CSS - see here for how to [add your own CSS to Nova](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/customization/themes.html).

Using the slug of my Leads resource, I can refer to the dusk attribute by slug and resource section:

```
div[dusk="leads-index-component"] table td.td-fit span:last-of-type {
    display: none !important;
}
```

So the part you'd change is the `leads-index-component` part to be `{your-resource-slug}-index-component`

Also, just remove the `:last-of-type` part if you want to hide both the view and the edit icon:

[image]

For reference, I am using the [Button Field package](https://novapackages.com/packages/dillingham/nova-button) to add the custom button to redirect to my own custom tool for management of this resource.

*I am not affiliated with any of the links provided.*

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to do something similar. I didn't want the edit button to appear at the index page, but I wanted the actions to run (and update the resources). So I used the code below:

```
use Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\ActionRequest;

...

public function authorizedToUpdate(Request $request)
{
    return $request instanceof ActionRequest;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works for me in index and details page it's the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the custom actions and set the action visibility as per your requirements.

1. Create New **Action Class**:

```
# To generate the action class
php artisan nova:action DeleteUserData --destructive
```

2. Set **Action Visibility:**

```
/**
 * Indicates if this action is only available on the resource index view.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
public $onlyOnIndex = false;

/**
 * Indicates if this action is only available on the resource detail view.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
public $onlyOnDetail = true;
```

Src: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/actions/defining-actions.html#action-visibility

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I was expecting, if we can set some property and get it done.

Comment: There is not any provision for the `action` items but you can do this for the `fields` :)

Comment: okay, thank you for pointing out that. In Nova 2.0 too, they are is no such option or you are talking about 1.0 only?

Comment: It's there for 2.0 as well https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/actions/defining-actions.html#action-visibility

Comment: I think you got my last question wrong, I was asking in 2.0, too, we can not disable / enable visibility on edit/delete ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195274/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-vikash-pathak).

Comment: Yes.. in nova 2.0 you can't set the visibility for the predefined actions like your requirements.

Comment: ok, thank you, have they mentioned that anywhere or you found it during your work? any way a great point for documentation if not mentioned .

Comment: I'm checking documentation update.. https://github.com/laravel/nova-docs/blob/develop/2.0/actions

Comment: You can do it by creating policy and returning false on `update()` and adding `authorizable()` on resource class.

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative just using css.

```css
    div[dusk$="-index-component"] table td.td-fit {
     display: none !important;
    }
```

Comment: I want to hide just a view button, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Only a CSS solution seems to exist, such as:

```
/* Details page */
div[dusk="users-detail-component"] button[dusk="open-delete-modal-button"],
/* Index page next to each row */
div[dusk="users-index-component"] button[dusk$="-delete-button"],
/* Index page after checking boxes */
div[dusk="users-index-component"] div[dusk="delete-menu"] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Enter your components name, in this case it's `users-`.

Other solutions that involve authorization and policies will not only hide button, but disable the action completely, so you won't be able to run it with a custom action if needed.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but I tried to change -delete- to -view- and it does not work? How can I remove just a view button instead of a delete button? Thanks

Comment: @ChristopherKikoti It depends on which model you're using it, you'll need to replace `users-index-component`, try inspect the element to see what it's called.