# how to remove all checkboxes from resource list in laravel nova?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a laravel nova app. Like other nova app on resource list it shows a checkbox before every rows. and a option of select all.

[image: Here is the screenshot of those checkboxes]

I want to remove those checkboxes from the resource list.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far? Do you have any code you could show?

Comment: I didn't tried anything yet. just confused what to try. if u have any suggestion it will be great....

Comment: Can you speak to why you don't want them? As far as I know they can be hidden, when the current user has no delete permissions ...

Comment: yeah i know that too. I just want them hide so that all row can't be delete with just one click . but i  want that individual delete option too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in comments above, the cleanest way will be limiting user permissions. Otherwise, there are some hacky ways to try:

**1. Empty actions**

If you resource has no actions, then in your resource file override `availableActions` method:

```php
/**
 * Get the actions that are available for the given request.
 *
 * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
 */
public function availableActions(NovaRequest $request)
{
    return [];
}
```

**2. Hiding with css.**

Put this in custom tool, or override `layout.blade.php`.

**EDIT** Found a better way of hiding with css thanks to [@Max's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60536285/2288496)

```css
div[dusk="products-index-component"] div[dusk="select-all-dropdown"],
div[dusk="products-index-component"] .table td:first-child,
div[dusk="products-index-component"] .table th:first-child {
  display: none !important;
}
```

**3. Custom `resource-index` component.**

Create custom tool and override `/nova/resources/js/views/Index.vue`. This is where checkbox showing logic goes on.

```js
/**
 * Determine whether to show the selection checkboxes for resources
 */
shouldShowCheckBoxes() {
  return (
    Boolean(this.hasResources && !this.viaHasOne) &&
    Boolean(
      this.actionsAreAvailable ||
        this.authorizedToDeleteAnyResources ||
        this.canShowDeleteMenu
    )
  )
},
```

Comment: But have another qus how to precise it for specific resource .? suppose i have a user and post resource i only want the feature at the user resource so that all user can't be deleted at once.. but still want the delete all feature at post resource ....

Comment: @tanvirofficials updated my answer in "Hiding with css" section. Just change resource name in my case "products"