# Haw to disable posibility to Select All at Nova Panel

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I want to disbale posibiliy for Select all option at the Nova Panel
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyrwI.png)
Becasue select all rise a new problem it is posibility to force delete items.

But if Selected all is checked that Force Delete is allow for multiple items.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsDZc.png)

Haw can i disable force delete for multiple items? Or haw to disable Select all checkbox at Nova Panel.

I am add function to resourses to disable force deleting.
    `public function authorizedToForceDelete(Request $request) { return false; }`
But that method work only for one item not for multiple.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to remove all checkboxes from resource list in laravel nova?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60649630/how-to-remove-all-checkboxes-from-resource-list-in-laravel-nova)